# Error loading an image to a UIImageView in a CustomCell

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitableview

I'm trying to build a menu using a UItableView with Custom cells which have an image and some additional text. However, when I try to load the image using the code below I get a SIGABRT error, why?

```
        imageTmp = [UIImage imageNamed: @"HR1.jpg"];
        cell.image = [UIImageView setImage:imageTmp];
```

The UIImageView is called image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be

```
cell.imageView.image  = imageTmp;
```